# Windows 10 installation/restore stuck

Tags: windows-10, installation, system-restore

My niece got a computer for Christmas (new HP, not sure of specs outside of i5 processor per sticker), and promptly got a virus.  She tried to run through the system restore process, but the installation has been stuck at 64% for 8+ hours (reported 4 hours at her house, and subsequently 4 hours at mine), and reboots itself every 10 or 15 minutes or so.  I have been unable to find a way to do anything at this point.

How do I either abort and restart the installation/restore, or get it to continue?

Comment: HP factory restore is a long process and will reboot on its own many times, do not interrupt the process.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have access to a different computer and a USB drive, I would recommend creating an external recovery media. [Link](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10ISO).
Then boot to the USB (hold [`f9`](http://support.hp.com/us-en/document/c01443326) while starting up, and selecting your USB drive. It is possible that the recovery partition has been damaged and/or corrupted, and a clean installation media might fix you problems.

Do Note: since Windows 8, windows laptops almost never ship with a licence key sticker, the key is hard coded into the motherboard, and as long as you chose the right version of windows (in your case windows 10 [not pro]), you can skip the activation step in the recover/reinstall process and it will automatically activate once Windows starts.

Comment: Ultimately this is what I did, with a fresh install, and all was well.

Answer (score -1):

Disregarding all suggestions above - finally (12 hours at least) have it installed, restart needed , fingers crossed on that , just take it a time, the loooong one though